# What are these phrases called?

Tags: conjunctions

Tragic yet beautiful;
 Pretty yet ugly;
Cold yet sweating;
Hot yet shivering;
Scary yet funny;
Serious yet funny;

What are these called? phrases with the word yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't specifically dealing with the word "yet," but whenever you describe something with 2 seemingly contradictory (opposite) terms, it's called an oxymoron.

Examples:

-Jumbo shrimp

-Deafening silence

-Growing smaller

-Original copy

-Passive aggressive

-Small crowd

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would say they are not oxymorons. The examples you listed, which are oxymoronic, are different than the those in the question; the examples in the question are more akin to juxtaposition, IMHO.

Comment: I agree with tidbertum

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there's anything special about the word *yet*.  You've listed some adjectival phrases, in which *yet* functions as a conjunction largely synonymous with *but*.